# Android BroadcastReceiver security - necessary to check intent for originator package?

Tags: android

I want to make sure that the Intent received by my BroadcastReceiver is from my app, instead of another app.

Is it necessary to add security checks to make sure that the intent originated in my app ?
Is there a mechanism in place that I need to enable ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:exported="false"` in manifest declaration of BroadcastReceiver. This makes sure only intents from your app can launch it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction, I learned that since my receiver doesn't have an intent-filter, it's implicitly set to exported=false :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), which is meant to send and receive intent local to your process.

Comment: Thanks for this too - I didn't know about this Class